# POST requests for incoming events

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a webhook for Twitter's event, I don't understand POST requests for incoming events, can anybody give me a hint on how to do this on Net Core 3.1?, I have tried below but not sure what I did. I need advice. thank you so much

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Twitter/")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Listen()
    {
        string _json_response = string.Empty;

        try
        {
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                string _json = (await reader.ReadToEndAsync()).Trim();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_json))
                {
                    Helper.SaveLog("TwitterController.Listen : here 2  " + _json, Helper.Log_Mode.Info);
                }

                Task.WaitAll();
            }
            
        }

        return Content(_json, "application/json");
        
    }
```

I expect to get the CRC challenge in the above POST, but it doesn't arrive there

Comment: Please be more specific: **exactly what part** of [Twitter's webhook documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/account-activity-api/guides/getting-started-with-webhooks) are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Edited, I expect to get the CRC challenge in there, but it doesn't arrive

Comment: Twitter's documentation states: "a first step is writing code that receives a Twitter Challenge Response Check (CRC) **`GET`** request" - which is _not_ a `POST` request, but for some reason you've overlooked that part of their documentation...

Comment: yes, that's stated, " Make sure your web app supports POST requests for incoming events.", that's what I don't understand

Comment: BTW, locals ("variables") in C# should not have underscore-prefixed names (so your `_json` should be named `json`). The current  mainstream .NET naming convention is to only use underscore-prefixed names for `static` fields (and use `this` for all non-`static` instance field references) - though it's also not-uncommon to see projects using underscore-prefixes for non-`static` instance field names too, though I only tend to see this in much older codebases.

Comment: A `GET` request is not a `POST` request. Twitter's documentation states that their webhook system will make both `GET` and `POST` requests to your webhook. The fact you need to support `POST` requests is a [_necessary but not sufficient_ requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) to work with Twitter's webhooks.

Comment: they will make GET and POST to the same method?

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/Twitter/")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Listen_Get()
 
       [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Twitter/")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
       public async Task<ActionResult> Listen_Post()

like this?

Comment: **Yes**, [please go and actually read the documentation in-depth where this is mentioned](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/account-activity-api/guides/securing-webhooks) - but more specifically: They will make `GET` and `POST` requests  To the same **endpoint URI**, which is not necessarily a single C# method: you can have different C# methods handle requests for the same URI but which handle different HTTP verbs: that's what `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` are for.